# Flash RTMP streaming with no filename - How to connect?

Tags: flash, streaming, rtmp, real-time

Hello good people of SO.  I am building a flash media player for an live audio stream.  The server is set up to stream from a url that looks like so:

```
rtmp://ourwowzaserver.net:80/ourfiledirectory
```

the instructions i have found say to first set the directory:

```
nc.connect("rtmp://ourwowzaserver.net:80/ourfiledirectory");
```

and then later play it:

```
nc.play(mp3:thefilename)
```

this works when we have discrete filenames on the server (thefilename), but the live stream is not a file - `rtmp://ourwowzaserver.net:80/shoutcast`.  How in the heck do I get .play to play it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a live stream on your server first.

When you have created the stream, you can play it by calling:

(nc is your NetConnection object)

```
NetStream liveStream = new NetStream(nc);
liveStream.play("streamName");
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use the root directory ie just the bare url and use shoutcast for the stream identifier

Then there's a bit of a trick to this.

You need to first create a net connection...

```
var myNC:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
myNC.connect("rtmp://ourwowzaserver.net:80");
```

...then **WAIT** 
You can't setup a NetStream until the NetConnection connect succeeds

on success you can then create a netstream

```
var myNS:NetStream = new NetStream(myNC);
myNS.play("shoutcast");
```